# Best practices in writing a SDK in Android studio?

Tags: android

So, I'm currently writing an Andorid library which will be used in my future projects, but I'm absolutely confused about how I go around building it in Android Studio using Gradle.

To test the library, and its usability, I need to import it to a Android project with an Activity in it, an apk that I can launch. So, these are my questions related to it.

If the sdk currently lives outside the "libs" folder, how do I import it into a Android app to test? For every change in code, do I've to copy the lib into the Android app/libs folder, and compile or is there a better way?

If this isn't the right way to do it, should I just write the entire library inside the Android app/libs folder?

Answer (score 1):

If the sdk currently lives outside the "libs" folder,then u should import it by
adding it to ***settings.gradle*** and then **add** the depenciency in **depencies** of **build**.**gradle**

Now, Answer for you second Question is :

So there are basically 2 ways of writing a Sdk  in Android studio.

*First Case:*
U can add modules by right clicking in ur **app** then from there u shud go to **Open Module Settings** or directlty use the shortcut key "**F4**" thereafter add module depenency by browsing from the computer which finally adds the function of the Sdk.

*Second Case:*
You can simply *add the given dependency in dependencies of* **buil.gradle.**

Yes,for every change in code,u hve to copy the library into the Android app/libs folder and then compile/**sync** it.

*But in that case what happens is that your previous codes won"t match with the new library as because new library comes up with new methods and functions.*

> For example to clear all your doubts:If you are using Facebook Sdk 3.0
>   then when later on when you update it with the newer library say
>   Facebook Sdk 4.0 then previous codes will not match so that in that
>   case,your old codes will not match and have to provide newer codes. SO
>   in this case,if you have already included facebook sdk 3.0 then there
>   is no need of Changing the library file of depencies into newer
>   version because for that you have to again toil hard to rewrite the
>   new codes.  Again,if you follow the first step of adding modules for
>   the facebook sdk then you dont have to change the codes because the
>   module will run the codes which is already defined in it.....there is
>   no question of syncing or taking a update.Therefore you cant update
>   it....hence leading to no change in codes because its using the
>   defined functions in the module

So in my opinion,if u add modules then it will take little more time in browsing it and then adding it but on the other hand, you can simply add a one line code of the Sdk (u want to use)in depencies and then sync it and then write its corresponding codes.

**But u have to remember, u should"nt update it and sync it with the newer version of the Sdk.**